# Two instances of same class cannot produce any methods. (Event Bus otto)

Tags: android, event-bus, otto

I have encountered a situation where I have a class (let's call this class "A") with a @Produce method.

In another class, if I initialize two objects from class "A". Event bus throws an exception that the producer class is already registered.

Is there any workaround for this? because I want to @Produce some functionality but also cannot avoid instantiation of the same class twice.

Comment: are you registering the event bus in constructor of Class A ?

Comment: @Basiljose yes I am

Comment: you can check whether object is already registered or not , have  you tried it ?

Comment: @Basiljose Yes and since there are two instances of the same class. trying to produce it gives the following error.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Producer method for type class com.data.model.FilterDataModel found on type class com.data.filter.FormSpinnerComponent, but already registered by type class com.data.filter.FormSpinnerComponent.